# Guzzle returns stream empty body instead of json body

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

When I use Postman to make an API call I receive a JSON object..which is what I expected.[image]

However When I make same call with Guzzle like so:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.dev/']);

$response = $client->request('GET', 'search', [
    'verify' => false,
]);

var_dump($response->getBody()); //null

var_dump($response); //returns below
```

I get dump below from Guzzle

```
Response {#304 ▼
  -reasonPhrase: "OK"
  -statusCode: 200
  -headers: array:8 [▼
    "Server" => array:1 [▶]
    "Content-Type" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "application/json"
    ]
    "Transfer-Encoding" => array:1 [▶]
    "Connection" => array:1 [▶]
    "Cache-Control" => array:1 [▶]
    "Date" => array:1 [▶]
    "X-RateLimit-Limit" => array:1 [▶]
    "X-RateLimit-Remaining" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  -headerNames: array:8 [▼
    "server" => "Server"
    "content-type" => "Content-Type"
    "transfer-encoding" => "Transfer-Encoding"
    "connection" => "Connection"
    "cache-control" => "Cache-Control"
    "date" => "Date"
    "x-ratelimit-limit" => "X-RateLimit-Limit"
    "x-ratelimit-remaining" => "X-RateLimit-Remaining"
  ]
  -protocol: "1.1"
  -stream: Stream {#302 ▼
    -stream: stream resource @15 ▼
      wrapper_type: "PHP"
      stream_type: "TEMP"
      mode: "w+b"
      unread_bytes: 0
      seekable: true
      uri: "php://temp"
      options: []
    }
    -size: null
    -seekable: true
    -readable: true
    -writable: true
    -uri: "php://temp"
    -customMetadata: []
  }
}
```

Comment: You get the same response when casting the body as a string?  `var_dump((string)$response->getBody());`

Comment: Does `$response->json();` exist? Not sure which version you're using.

Comment: What headers do you send along while using postman? (8 of them).

Comment: Iam using version 6, $response->json() does not exists

Answer (score 85, accepted):

`getBody()` returns a stream. If you want to get all the content at once you can use `getContents()` method and decode json while at it (if you need to)

```sql
$payload = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
```

Further reading - [Guzzle Responses](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/psr7.html#responses)

Comment: best answer i found for object not found or null with guzzle, thanks

Comment: The answer can be simplified to `json_decode($response->getBody())`. `json_decode()` will cast the body to `string` which has the same effect as calling `getContents()`.

Comment: @MaksimIvanov No it does not cast body to `string`.

Comment: @EmreAydin https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @MaksimIvanov `json_decode` expects first argument to be string. `getBody()` does not return string.

Comment: @EmreAydin correct, it expects the first argument to be string. And if it's not string, it casts it to string.

Comment: @MaksimIvanov As I experimented lately, it didn't. That's why I ended up in this thread..

Comment: @EmreAydin and I have working code that relies on this cast :) could be that our PHP versions are different.

Comment: In windows local environment, PHP 7.2 and PHP 7.3 both returns empty string with `$response->getBody()->getContents()`. Had to use `json_decode($response->getBody());`.

Comment: That actually solved my problems with the oauth/token post request that I had. Proving that GuzzleHttp and all auxiliary functions were fetching the data and there was no problem with them. I just couldn't see the presented stream. Exceptional Answer!

Comment: As @Milan Markovic mentioned above, `$response->getBody()->getContents()` may return nothing if the pointer is already at the end. Please keep this in mind.

Answer (score 31):

If `$response->getBody()->getContents()` doesn't work for you, try:

```
$response->getBody()->__toString();
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/pull/1262#issuecomment-149080749), sometimes `getContents`'s stream pointer is already at the end of stream and then it returns empty response, but `__toString` resets it by default.

Comment: This one worked for me. Is there any way to convert this string to PHP array?

Comment: You just made my day. That made me really mad until I have found your answer. This seems still not to be solved that, I simply do not understand why they are doing this with the stream pointer. Any reason and any way to reset it?

Comment: I must say thank you for pointing us to this tricky thing! You've saved my day too!

Comment: wow thanks worked for me. thankssssss

Comment: Call the rewind method before getContents: `$body = $response->getBody(); $body->rewind(); print $body->getContents();`

Answer (score 0):

Milan's solution worked for me but the response coming from API was malformed.

I had to use `stripslashes` to convert it to a PHP array:

```
$response = $response->getBody()->__toString();
$response =  stripslashes($response);
$data = json_decode($response, true);
```